# Adding a Style to QGIS

Tags: qgis, symbology, style

I've downloaded the VA Geological Survey data set (http://mrdata.usgs.gov/geology/state/state.php?state=VA) that I have already on Google Earth as a kmz. The various formations are color coded. There's a style file (lith6_2.style) that QGIS doesn't seem to recognize, although ArcGIS has an instruction set to activate it (http://mrdata.usgs.gov/geology/state/style_help.html). Is there a way to do that in QGIS?

Comment: What's the format/extension/whatever of the style file?

Comment: lith6_2.style is the filename

Comment: Can you **edit** your question to include a link to the ArcGIS instruction set you found? Addressing it in QGIS directly may not be possible, but if it can be done in ArcGIS somehow, knowing that method might help answerers adapt it to QGIS or suggest a process with an intermediate step/format/software that can get you there.

Comment: It looks like there's no easy/free way at the moment. You might dig through these related questions: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/31759/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3755/ or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/77104/. This might actually be duplicate of one (or both) of the first two, but the answer there appears to be a software that is no longer free. The third question is more going the other way (QGIS to Arc). You may just have to manually build a new QGIS style based on looking at the other source.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS can read QML and SLD style files. If you only have access to proprietary style formats,  QGIS won't be able to read those because the specifications are not public.